# Nullable Method Arguments in C#

Tags: c#, arguments, nullable

**Duplicate Question**

[Passing null arguments to C# methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271588/passing-null-arguments-to-c-methods/271600)

Can I do this in c# for .Net 2.0?

```
public void myMethod(string astring, int? anint)
{
//some code in which I may have an int to work with
//or I may not...
}
```

If not, is there something similar I can do?

Comment: I did a search and the duplicate didn't come up or that would have answered this. Thanks all.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, assuming you added the chevrons deliberately and you really meant:

```
public void myMethod(string astring, int? anint)
```

`anint` will now have a `HasValue` property.

Answer (score 21):

Depends on what you want to achieve. If you want to be able to drop the `anint` parameter, you have to create an overload:

```
public void myMethod(string astring, int anint)
{
}

public void myMethod(string astring)
{
    myMethod(astring, 0); // or some other default value for anint
}
```

You can now do:

```
myMethod("boo"); // equivalent to myMethod("boo", 0);
myMethod("boo", 12);
```

If you want to pass a nullable int, well, see the other answers. ;)

Comment: +1 good suggestion to use polymorphism

Comment: @Garry, yep your right it isn't.

Comment: I think you can avoid the overload by a definition like: `public void myMethod(string astring, int? anint = null)`. This way you can call to the method only with a string as parameter and the value of the anint variable will be null; and also call it with the string and the integer.

Answer (score 11):

In C# 2.0 you can do;

```
public void myMethod(string astring, int? anint)
{
   //some code in which I may have an int to work with
   //or I may not...
}
```

And call the method like

```
 myMethod("Hello", 3);
 myMethod("Hello", null);
```