# How to pass one null parameters to the main class?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, parameters, console-application

Below sample code takes two string parameters from cmd such as

```
c:\myprogram.exe bobby henn
```

output

```
first name is bobby
last name is henn
```

but when I pass only one parameter it throwing me an error even i specified the length in if case

```
c:\myprogram.exe bobby
```

> Unhandled Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was
>   outside the bounds of the array.  at command.Program1.Main(String[]
>   args)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;

namespace command
{
   public class Program
    {
       public void ben(string bobby, string x)
        {

          if (bobby == null |  x.Length < 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Empty value, pass any parameter");
            }

            else
             {

                Console.WriteLine("First Name is " + bobby);
                Console.WriteLine("Last Name is " + x);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

    }

    class Program1
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
         Program glb = new Program();
         glb.ben(bobby:args[0],x:args[1]);
        }
    }

}
```

And also is there any other way to call the parameters to main method instead of `bobby:args[0],x:args[1]`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/271600/3585278

Comment: You have to check how many arguments are passed into `Main`. If it's only one, you'll have to call `ben` with `string.Empty` or `null`.

Comment: @Danieboy: its not so much about passing null parameters - it is the issue of the array bounds exception - which can only be resolved with checking number of parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ElementAtOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb494386(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method from `System.Linq`, instead of the square brackets operator:

```
glb.ben(bobby:args.ElementAtOrDefault(0), x:args.ElementAtOrDefault(1));
```

It will return `null` if index is out of range for the given array, instead of throwing the exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
         Program glb = new Program();

         if(args.length==2) 
         glb.ben(args[0],x:args[1]);
         else
         glb.ben(args[0]);
        }
```

And change this

```
     public void ben(string bobby, string x = null)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always sanitize user input as a first step. In this case, if both parameters are required, you could print an error message and then exit.

About your second question, you could use EnvironmentGetCommandLineArgs() but this returns an string array anyway.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers dealing with checking number of input parameters : as long as you are passing the parameters in the defined order then you do not need to prefix with the parameter name

```
glb.ben(bobby:args[0],x:args[1]);
```

can be simplified to

```
glb.ben(args[0],args[1]);
```

If you wanted to pass the parameters in a different order then you could use

```
glb.ben(x:args[1], bobby:args[0]);
```

Comment: While not an issue in your case, there is a small performance hit with naming parameters - the compiler generates temporary variables to the named parameters & then uses the temporary variables in the correct order for the actual call to the method.